# How can I format the following text?

Tags: python, text

I have this text:

```
[b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'018', b'0998', b'0000']
[b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'018', b'0999', b'0000']
[b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'024', b'0150', b'0000']
[b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'033', b'1892', b'0000']
[b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'036', b'0100', b'0000']
[b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'040', b'0300', b'0000']
[b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'041', b'0100', b'0000']
```

How can I format the text such as the result is:

```
897 7W 7W 018 0998 0000
897 7W 7W 018 0999 0000
897 7W 7W 024 0150 0000
etc...
```

I thought of something like the below, but it does not work because there are multiple things to remove:

```
 data = a.read()
        data = data.replace("", "")
        a.write(data)
```

Comment: use this as an example? `' '.join(map(lambda string: string.decode(), [b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'018', b'0998', b'0000']))`. Also I would highly suggest you use the [`with ... as ...:`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) approach to read the file first. Process it and then write to it. Don't have the stream open for reading and just write back to it

Comment: `b' '.join(data)`

Comment: The text seems valid Python code. Is it part of your Python code, or a separate text file you want to convert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty simple to do using `.join()` and `.decode()`:

```
lst = [b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'018', b'0998', b'0000']

b" ".join(lst).decode("utf-8")
```

Output:

```
'897 7W 7W 018 0998 0000'
```

In the case you need to do multiple:

```
lsts = [[b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'018', b'0998', b'0000'], [b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'018', b'0999', b'0000']]

formatted = [b" ".join(lst).decode("utf-8") for lsts in list]
```

Output:

```
['897 7W 7W 018 0998 0000', '897 7W 7W 018 0999 0000']
```

Answer (score 0):

From your post, it appears that you have multiple lists of ["bytes"](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#binary-sequence-types-bytes-bytearray-memoryview) items:

```
>>> l = [b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'018', b'0998', b'0000']
>>> l
[b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'018', b'0998', b'0000']
>>> print(l)
[b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'018', b'0998', b'0000']
>>> l[0]
b'897'

>>> type(l[0])
<class 'bytes'>
```

Bytes items need to be decoded into a specific encoding for printing, and it looks like UTF-8 will work for your data:

```
>>> for i in l:
...     print(i.decode("utf-8"))
...
897
7W
7W
018
0998
0000
```

There are many, many things to know about encodings, and [this](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) is a classic (2003) post to get you started.

[Assuming Modern Python (Python 3+)]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to remove everything except new-lines, spaces, numbers and uppercase letters:

```
data = """[b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'018', b'0998', b'0000']
[b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'018', b'0999', b'0000']
[b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'024', b'0150', b'0000']
[b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'033', b'1892', b'0000']
[b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'036', b'0100', b'0000']
[b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'040', b'0300', b'0000']
[b'897', b'7W', b'7W', b'041', b'0100', b'0000']"""

import re
data = re.sub(r"[^ 0-9A-Z\n]","",data)
print(data) # outputFile.write(data)

897 7W 7W 018 0998 0000
897 7W 7W 018 0999 0000
897 7W 7W 024 0150 0000
897 7W 7W 033 1892 0000
897 7W 7W 036 0100 0000
897 7W 7W 040 0300 0000
897 7W 7W 041 0100 0000
```

Or, you could select the values between single quotes and join them with a space separator:

```
data = "\n".join( " ".join(re.findall("'([^']*)'",line)) for line in data("\n"))
```